# Select tag gets "disabled" on a certain screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a new weird html/bootstrap/jquery problem... When the screen have a certain width (more than the nav-toggle width, but less than the normal width), all select boxes gets "disabled".

Check my [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g28403va/). Notice then on wide screens it works perfectly, but on medium sies it does not show, while om small it works good again.

Don't really know how to search for this problem, but the searches I have done have returned nothing of interrest. Hope you guys have a clue...

I have tested the latest Chrome, and IE, an interresting thing though is that earlier versions of IE works as expected (9 and 10), but Edge/11 does not work.

```
<div class="container kidliste" style="" id="HEADER_243">
    <div class="row" onclick="clickMessageList(243);">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="text-left" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 0.8em; margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 2px">
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;27.02.2014 - 23:31&nbsp;
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="text-right" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 0.8em;">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;40055206&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <p style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 1.2em; margin: 3px;">
                    <a style=" ">test pricegroup</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 text- text-right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default midliste" data-kid="243" id="MELDINGER_243" style="margin: 0 0 25px 80px">
    <div class="panel" style="margin: 2px;padding: 0; margin-bottom: 5; padding-bottom: 0; color: #D17600">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding: 2px; margin-left: 15px">
                27.02.2014 - 23:31                    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="display: inline-block ; min-height: 3em;">
                test pricegroup                    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right text-right" style="margin-right: 25px;">
                <a onclick="confirmSensur(1043, 243)" style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: 0.8em;">Sensurer melding!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="margin: 2px;padding: 0; margin-bottom: 5; padding-bottom: 0; color: grey">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding: 2px; margin-left: 15px">
                27.02.2014 - 23:31                    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7" style="display: inline-block ; min-height: 3em;">
                Meldingen er mottatt og vil bli behandlet så snart som mulig. Mvh Legene på Høyden                    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 pull-right text-right" style="margin-right: 25px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="margin: 2px;padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-left: 15px"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form class="form-inline sendMessage" id="sendMessage_243" role="form" method="post" action="index2.php?page=Innboks&amp;action=sendMelding">
                    <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="243">
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="0">

                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn btnStandardmelding" onclick="$(this).MessageWiz('#TEXT_243')">
                                Standardmelding <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        <textarea id="TEXT_243" name="msg" class="form-control custom-control" rows="2" style="resize:none;"></textarea>

                        <span onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit()" class="input-group-addon btn">Send</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" style="margin: 2px;padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-left: 15px"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form id="oppdaterStatus_243" action="index2.php?page=Innboks&amp;action=oppdaterStatus" method="post" class="form-horizontal oppdaterStatus">
                    <input type="hidden" name="kid" value="243">

                    <div class="form-group container" style="margin-left: -15px">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="innboks">Flytt:</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select class="input-xlarge form-control" name="innboks" id="innboks">
                                <option value="2">Ferdig</option>
                                <option value="1" selected="">Ubehandlet
                                </option>
                                <option value="4">Diverse</option>
                                <option value="3">Arbeidsliste
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="tag">Tag:</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select id="tag" class="input-xlarge form-control" name="tag">
                                <option value="0">-</option>
                                <option value="1">Morten Andre Pedersen</option>
                                <option value="2">Richard Hagen</option>
                                <option value="47">Ola Nordmann</option>
                                <option value="58">Test Testesen</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-right col-md-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Lagre oppdatering</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Protip: You're way overusing the `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I know, its a prototype page, so I will be cleaining everything up as soon as it works...

Comment: The "Lagre oppdatering" button is displaying as a block element and covers the floating elements to the left (so you can't click them). Changing its style from `text-align: right` to `float: right` fixes it. But if you want to display elements below, you're going to need to use `clear: both` eventually.

Comment: Wow, thanks! If you write an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Lagre oppdatering" button is displaying as a block element and covers the floating elements to the left (so you can't click them). Changing its style from `text-align: right` to `float: right` fixes it. But if you want to display elements below, you're going to need to use `clear: both` eventually.